# Facetime call history & Facebook message history

Tags: facetime, facebook

Do FaceTime calls show up on my phone bill???  Is there a way for me to find out if someone on my shared account is making and/or receiving FaceTime calls and, if so, to/from whom?  Basically, what I'm asking is if there is any way for me to find out if my husband is using FaceTime to talk to another woman?  Without actually taking his phone and snooping or using an app like FONEPAW?  What about messages sent thru Facebook?  Can those be accessed without his phone?

Answer (score 1):

FaceTime calls do not show-up as 'FaceTime' on your phone bill.  It's simply a data transfer so it will be lumped-in with all other data transfers on your bill, you don't know what type of data it was, either.

FaceTime calls (audio and video) all go thru Apple's servers so they have a record of the calls.   Also, the iPhone stores the FaceTime history in a local database.  You can search this site for examples of software and techniques to get access to that database and look at it.  They all require you to jailbreak the iPhone so you'd need access to it for an extended period of time.

For Facebook, I believe you can search the history as long as it hasn't been deleted.  [Here's an article](http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/manage-recover-your-facebook-chat-messages-history-0146925/) on how to so that.  It's a few years old but I believe it's still technically correct.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I thought but a friend told me that I could contact my provider and find out if he was using FaceTime to make ANY phone calls.

Comment: Yea, sorry, that's not true.  The service provider doesn't know anything about it, that's why people like & use it.

Comment: @fsb I don't believe that's technically true. Providers are able to block FaceTime over cellular, so clearly there's something they can identify it with, whether it's traffic over a certain port, or the device itself sends an identifying header. That said I don't believe they have any ability to know the other device involved in a conversation.

Comment: Yes, technically they can block it (via the carrier settings on the device itself) but in the context of this question the provider would not know who made or received a facetime call nor know the contents of any call,adequate.

Comment: the latest comment by @KimCaraway-MorenoCalderon  says that she wants to know about ANY calls. Would the service provider know if FaceTime was used or not?